# Effect of Low credit hours/ long undergrad on grad school

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

I am studying Computer Science as an undergrad and I have been doing a low number of credit hours per semester (less than 15, but still full time). Am I at a disadvantage when applying for grad school?

By the time I graduate, I would have completed 5 years, when normally this is a 4 year degree. My GPA is relatively good, a 3.85 on a 4.00 scale, but I am afraid it will be attributed to the low workload.

Comment: `attributed to the low workload` Or appropriate workload?

Comment: It was the appropriate workload for me, but might be seen as low by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think taking a little bit of extra time is going to make a huge difference in your case is viewed by admissions staff, so long as you've been putting the extra time to good use. Have you used the extra time to do research? Have you done summer internships or research programs?

If all you've done is lengthen your undergraduate program with nothing but good coursework to show for it, then extra time may hurt you.

Comment: By the time I graduate, I would have completed two internships, but no research as of yet :/

Comment: 5 years seems to be more like the norm than the exception, at least with my small network of acquaintances. What makes you think this would hurt him at all?

Comment: Furthering my previous comment, I could actually think of rationale of why taking longer is better. I finished in 3 years and feel like it hurt me far more than it did good.